# Processing mulitiple files line by line in Perl

Tags: perl, file, glob

I'm trying to look for multiple files using *glob()* and then process each file line by line.
 When I run this:

```
my @dir = glob($ARGV[0]);
foreach my $file (@dir){
    local $/ = undef;
    open (input, "<$file");

    while (my $line = <input>){   
        $line =~ ...
    }
    close(input);
}
```

it does open the files, but only works for the first line of every file. It exits the while-loop after just one iteration. Where is the flaw here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `local $/ = undef;` is your problem. `$/` stores the sequence of characters that define the end of a line. By setting it to `undef` you basically tell perl to read the complete file at once. [See perlvar for details](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: Argh.. copied that part from another script where I opened the files differently and didn't really think about it again.. Thanks a lot!